# Having an issue with SwiftUI and completion handlers

Tags: swiftui, completionhandler

I am trying to have a User select their username; if it is not already taken during registration they can proceed else they can not register.

I have the following:

```
Button(action: {

    if (self.verifyUsername(username: self.username)) {
                        
        withAnimation {
                           
            self.isTaC.toggle()
                            
        }
                    
    }) {
                    
        Text("Save Profile and Agree")
                    
    }
```

Which calls the following :

```
func verifyUsername(username: String) -> Bool {
    
    userStore.usernameExists(username: username) { flag in
        
        if (flag) {
            
            return true
        
        } else {
        
            return false
        
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

And finally the userstore that gets the info from Firebase:

```
func usernameExists(username: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    usernameRef.child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            
            print("Username Exists")
            completion(true)
            
        } else {
            
            print("Username DOESN'T Exists")
            completion(false)
            
        }
        
    })
    
}
```

I am getting a compiler error <<Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Bool'>> for the `userStore.usernameExists(username: username) { flag in` portion of my code which I do not understand why?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `verifyUsername` is supposed to return a `Bool`, but it doesn't. It only calls `userStore.usernameExists`, and since it's the only statement, there's an implied `return`, which whatever the returns return value of `userStore.usernameExists` is, which is.... `Void`, or `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verification is asynchronous, so you should work with callbacks instead of returned values.

So it should look like the following

```
Button("Save Profile and Agree") {

    self.verifyUsername(username: self.username)) {
        withAnimation {
            self.isTaC.toggle()
        }
    }                    

}

// ...

func verifyUsername(username: String, processForCorrect: @escaping () -> ()) {
    userStore.usernameExists(username: username) { flag in
        if (flag) {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            processForCorrect()
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx again... its working, I guess my only other question is how do I make it throw an error to inform the user about the username already being taken, which is why I had the func initially returning true/false so that then I could throw the error message to the user?